# Contour integral of absolute value of a function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

How is the contour integral with absolute value performed?

Here
$$\mathfrak{I}=\int_{C_1} \frac{a|z|}{z-\gamma}\mathrm{d}z$$
where the contour $C_1$ is parallel to the real line but passes above the point $z=\gamma$ and $a\in \mathbb{C}$

Is taking $z=R e^{i\theta}$ and hence $\mathrm{d}z=R i e^{i\theta}$ and taking the limit from $0$ to $\pi$ a correct approach?

That gives
$$\mathfrak{I}=\int_0^\pi \frac{aR}{Re^{i\theta}-\gamma}R i e^{i\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta=a R (\log (-\gamma -R)-\log (R-\gamma ))$$

but it does not seem to converge in the limit $R\to \infty$.

Comment: If $C_1$ is meant to be parallel to the real axis, then the appropriate parametrisation would be $z=(M-m) t + m + iX$ for $0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1$ and $X > \Im \gamma$;  you could then let $m \to -\infty$ and $M \to +\infty$.  The numerator $|z| $ is not constant on this line.  

Your integral is set out correctly but the contour is a semi-circle and not a straight line parallel to the real axis.

Comment: @WADon, how do I compute the numerator with that parameterization?

Comment: Its $\sqrt{(M-m)t +m )^2 + X^2}$.  Not that easy to deal with.  It is true on a first look that that the difference between the integral around semi-circular contour and that along the the straight line will have limit zero if you take $M=R, m=-R$ and let $R \to \infty $, but I do not think either has a finite limit on its own, although I've not worked it very hard.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear.  Given the contour $C_1=x+i k$ for constant k, then looks like your integral is:
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{a\sqrt{x^2+k^2}}{(x+ik)-\gamma}dx$$
$$=\biggr\{a \left(-\sqrt{\gamma } \sqrt{-\gamma +2 i k} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{k^2-i k x+\gamma  x}{\sqrt{\gamma } \sqrt{-\gamma +2 i k} \sqrt{k^2+x^2}}\right)+(\gamma -i k) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{k^2+x^2}}\right)+\sqrt{k^2+x^2}\right)\biggr\}\biggr|_{x1}^{x_2}$$

If it were mine, I would evaluate it numerically say from 1 to 10,  then compare the results with the expression above. However the antiderivative has multi-valued functions which will cause problems with a definite integral